# How to server multiple sites with nginx/passenger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, mod-rails

I have different websites/applications built with rails, which has different domain names. The thing is I want to serve them from a server with Nginx/passenger. I tried some techniques, but I cannot make them work, basically, I have very few information about this.

So, I can serve different websites/applications on different ports. But how can I make people to see application "AAA" if they are coming from aaa.com and see application "BBB" if they are coming from bbb.com?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Phusion Passenger's documentation has a passage on this here, section 3.2: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html

Basically, you can set up virtual hosts that point to different applications on the same web server/app server pair.

You can also do rewrites or forwarding purely through nginx configuration, if the above doesn't work.

Comment: if you can write a simple example that will be great, because i already tried to do what they wrote on that section